# How can I stop Apache2 from log certain warning messages?

Tags: apache-2.2, setenv

On my Apache `ErrorLog` file I see many times this warning message:

```
[Wed Aug 23 17:27:25.146025 2017] [:error] [pid 14989] [client 66.249.76.54:44935] PHP Warning:  Illegal offset type in isset or empty in /var/www/html/blog/wp-content/plugins/ilab-media-tools/classes/tools/s3/ilab-media-s3-tool.php on line 1012
```

I tried on [Github](https://github.com/Interfacelab/ilab-media-tools/issues/11) to ask help from author (as many others) but nothing.

Apache print this warning every minute, **is there a way to filter this annoying message warning?**

Comment: I can't find a solution on the web...moreover I can't use `combined` with the `ErrorLog` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the level of `error_reporting` in your php.ini file to the desired [level](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) to prevent the messages from getting generated in the first place, if you can't/won't fix the actual code that is triggering such messages.

By default everything except run-time notices get logged:

```
 error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

but maybe all you want are the fatal run-time errors:

```
 error_reporting = E_ERROR & E_CORE_ERROR
```